# Trying to seperate strings from a long list of headlines

Tags: python, json, string, sorting, intellij-idea

I'm using a news api for python and it ouputs everything into a long list of all the headlines and websites and things of that sort. The ouput looks like:

```
{'status': 'ok', 'totalResults': 38, 'articles': [{'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': 'Boeing to pay bereaved 737 families $144500 each - BBC News', 'description': 'The financial assistance fund Boeing set up after the crashes has started accepting claims.', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/business-49803068', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/104F2/production/_108920866_gettyimages-1167365351.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T22:38:36Z', 'content': 'Image copyrightGetty ImagesImage caption\r\n Families are to receive about $144,500 each\r\nFamilies who lost relatives in fatal Boeing 737 Max air crashes are set to receive about $144,500 (£116,200) each from the company.\r\nThe money comes from a $50m financial … [+2097 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Deadline.com'}, 'author': "Amanda N'Duka,Anthony D'Alessandro, Amanda N'Duka, Anthony D'Alessandro", 'title': 'Jonah Hill In Talks For Matt Reeves’ ‘The Batman’ At Warner Bros - Deadline', 'description': 'EXCLUSIVE:\xa0We are hearing that two-time Oscar nominee Jonah Hill is in talks to play a villain in the upcoming Warner Bros reboot The Batman, which stars Robert Pattinson as the Caped Crusader. Dea…', 'url': 'https://deadline.com/2019/09/jonah-hill-in-talks-for-matt-reeves-the-batman-at-warner-bros-1202742916/', 'urlToImage': 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/jonah-hill-e1569279089585.jpg?w=1024', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T22:08:00Z', 'content': 'EXCLUSIVE:\xa0We are hearing that two-time Oscar nominee Jonah Hill is in talks to play a villain in the upcoming Warner Bros reboot The Batman, which stars Robert Pattinson as the Caped Crusader. Deals aren’t signed yet, but that’s what we are hearing at this m… [+931 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'politico', 'name': 'Politico'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/daniellippman', 'title': 'The intelligence watchdog at the center of Ukraine firestorm - POLITICO', 'description': 'President Trump appointed Michael Atkinson, a widely respected career DOJ official, to keep the intelligence community accountable. Now, he’s unexpectedly in the middle of a presidential scandal.', 'url': 'https://www.politico.com/story/2019/09/23/atkinson-trump-ukraine-whistleblower-scandal-1508594', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.politico.com/ef/de/f06302cf41f1adb23c46ec335fd7/20190923-donald-trump-gty-773.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:47:00Z', 'content': 'President Donald Trump. | Spencer Platt/Getty Images\r\nThe intelligence communitys chief watchdog, Michael Atkinson, is known to his peers and colleagues as a highly cautious straight shooter who tends to keep his head down. \r\nSo when he sounded the alarm to C… [+1646 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Vox.com'}, 'author': 'Alex Ward', 'title': 'France, Germany, UK say Iran is responsible for Saudi Arabia attacks - Vox.com', 'description': '“It is clear for us that Iran bears responsibility for this attack,” the leaders of the three European powers said. “There is no other explanation.”', 'url': 'https://www.vox.com/world/2019/9/23/20880639/france-germany-uk-iran-saudi-statement', 'urlToImage': 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/15u8motId_osZOIlMdIE82FpJ20=/0x74:4584x2474/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19226096/1164153206.jpg.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:36:00Z', 'content': 'The Trump administration has blamed Iran for the attacks on two vital oil facilities belonging to Saudi Arabias state-run oil company Aramco nine days ago. That assertion was met with deep skepticism by politicians, experts, and even some US allies, mostly be… [+2588 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'cnbc', 'name': 'CNBC'}, 'author': 'Berkeley Lovelace Jr.', 'title': 'Federal prosecutors in California reportedly open criminal probe of vaping company Juul - msnNOW', 'description': "The probe by the U.S. attorney's office of the Northern District of California is in its early stages, the Journal reported, citing people familiar with the matter.", 'url': 'https://www.cnbc.com/2019/09/23/federal-prosecutors-conducting-criminal-probe-into-juul-wsj.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106040688-15640809580022019-02-06t180654z_1746289374_rc1220cf81f0_rtrmadp_3_global-vaping.jpg?v=1566493861', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:30:00Z', 'content': "Federal prosecutors in California are conducting a criminal probe into e-cigarette maker Juul, the Wall Street Journal reported Monday.\r\nThe probe, by the U.S. attorney's office of the Northern District of California, is in the early stages, the Journal repor… [+1291 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Cheatsheet.com'}, 'author': 'Julia Mullaney', 'title': "Here's Why You Won't See Prince Harry and Meghan Markle When They Fly Commercial -- Even If You're on Their Flight - Showbiz Cheat Sheet", 'description': "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle might be flying commercial, but you probably won't even notice.", 'url': 'https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/you-wont-see-prince-harry-meghan-markle-when-they-fly-commercial.html/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.cheatsheet.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Prince-Harry-Meghan-Markle-5.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:28:06Z', 'content': 'Prince Harry and Meghan Markle recently flew to South Africa — and they didnt take a private jet. After receiving backlash, the royal couple decided to fly commercial during their South Africa tour and will likely do so from now on (unless they choose to fly … [+4405 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Cnet.com'}, 'author': 'Richard Nieva', 'title': 'Google Play Pass launches subscription service with 350 games and apps for Android - CNET', 'description': 'The service includes games and other types of apps.', 'url': 'https://www.cnet.com/news/google-play-pass-launches-subscription-service-with-350-games-and-apps-for-android/', 'urlToImage': 'https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/lqMwloR5D-TSYlelhCE_ni0H6k0=/756x567/2019/09/23/a10682f1-d50d-4a55-82bc-c127f5da2c0f/play-pass-titles.png', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:20:00Z', 'content': 'Google to Apple: "Game on!"\r\nGetty Images\r\nGoogle on Monday launched Play Pass, a monthly subscription service that gives people access to a library of games and other apps on Google\'s Play Store, as the search giant experiments with new pricing models for it… [+2451 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': "'Toilet trouble' for Narendra Modi and Bill Gates - BBC News", 'description': "Why has an award honouring India's PM for building toilets for the poor become controversial?", 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-49738605', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/AB2D/production/_108912834_gettyimages-1170210337.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:19:13Z', 'content': "Image copyrightGetty Images\r\nIndian Prime Minster Narendra Modi's high-profile visit to the US includes an evening in New York, where he will be honoured for a flagship government scheme. But the celebrity event has turned controversial. \r\nIt all began with a… [+7088 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': 'US policeman suspended for arresting two six-year-olds - BBC News', 'description': 'A six-year-old girl was handcuffed and charged with battery, her grandmother told US media.', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-49803733', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/3DAF/production/_108919751_gettyimages-914038200.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:16:11Z', 'content': 'Image copyrightGetty ImagesImage caption\r\n At least one child was handcuffed (file photo)\r\nA US police officer has been suspended after arresting two six-year-olds at a school in Orlando, Florida. \r\nOne of the two was handcuffed after throwing a tantrum and k… [+1921 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'engadget', 'name': 'Engadget'}, 'author': 'Amrita Khalid', 'title': "Amazon's version of AirPods will reportedly offer fitness tracking - Engadget", 'description': "We still know very little about Amazon's AirPods competitor.", 'url': 'https://www.engadget.com/2019/09/23/amazon-version-of-airpods-will-reportedly-offer-fitness-tracking/', 'urlToImage': 'https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?thumbnail=1200%2C630&quality=80&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fo.aolcdn.com%2Fimages%2Fdims%3Fresize%3D2000%252C2000%252Cshrink%26image_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fs.yimg.com%252Fos%252Fcreatr-images%252F2019-09%252F5c09c1c0-de3f-11e9-bdfe-950638385d12%26client%3Da1acac3e1b3290917d92%26signature%3D523d1e94bea45e69a4c8d8d0236e9cf292f6db5e&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=a67c5ed6bc83cff482093753cb6296b2e24b6688', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:11:27Z', 'content': "It's unknown when exactly we'll catch a glimpse of these earbuds. Amazon is expected to unveil a host of new devices at its big hardware event on September 25th. As is typical, the company has remained silent on what exactly we can expect from the event. If l… [+621 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Yahoo.com'}, 'author': None, 'title': 'Kourtney Kardashian & Scott Disick Are Still Managing to Co-Parent Through Nanny Disaster - Yahoo Lifestyle', 'description': "It all began with a nanny and a scratch. The nanny quit, but the story just won't: Kourtney Kardashian and co-parent Scott Disick are still fielding comments, questions and downright judgment from all sides regarding their daughter Penelope, 7, who allegedly …", 'url': 'https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/kourtney-kardashian-scott-disick-still-210906682.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/3iaYPDZKhx7B6hPQNcT9GA--~B/dz0wO3NtPTE7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media.zenfs.com/en-US/sheknows_79/aee9db9ca589dd39edc80b04f0c273e3', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:09:00Z', 'content': 'Click here to read the full article.\r\nIt all began with a nanny and a scratch.\xa0The nanny quit, but the story just wont:\xa0Kourtney Kardashian\xa0and co-parent\xa0Scott Disick\xa0are still fielding comments, questions and downright judgment from all sides regarding their… [+3403 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Statnews.com'}, 'author': 'Helen Branswell', 'title': 'Vaccination strategy in long-running Ebola outbreak comes under fire - STAT', 'description': 'The World Health Organization’s vaccination strategy in the long-running Ebola outbreak in the Democratic Republic of the Congo is coming under fire.', 'url': 'https://www.statnews.com/2019/09/23/vaccination-strategy-in-long-running-ebola-outbreak-comes-under-fire/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/GettyImages-1160258652-1024x576.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:57:39Z', 'content': 'The World Health Organizations vaccination strategy in the long-running Ebola outbreak in the Democratic Republic of the Congo is coming under fire, with Doctors Without Borders accusing the agency of rationing vaccines and calling for an independent committe… [+8661 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Giants.com'}, 'author': 'John Schmeelk, Dan Salomone, Lance Medow', 'title': 'Cover 3: Takeaways from Giants vs. Buccaneers - Giants.com', 'description': "The Giants.com staffers give their reactions to Sunday's win in Tampa Bay.", 'url': 'https://www.giants.com/news/cover-3-takeaways-from-giants-vs-buccaneers', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_editorial_landscape_12_desktop/giants/axk3hdqjrvhv41ehktww', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:56:01Z', 'content': 'As Pat Shurmur pointed out in his postgame press conference, there are things a quarterback can be trained to improve upon. A quarterback can be trained to protect the football when he is in the pocket. A quarterback can be trained to get the ball out quicker… [+1987 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'time', 'name': 'Time'}, 'author': 'Associated Press', 'title': 'Face Transplant Recipient May Need a New Donor After Doctors Discover Tissue Damage - TIME', 'description': 'A woman who was severely burned in a domestic violence attack may have a second face transplant after doctors discovered tissue damage.', 'url': 'https://time.com/5684395/face-transplant-vermont-woman/', 'urlToImage': 'https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/face-transplant-recipient-tissue.jpg?quality=85&w=1024&h=628&crop=1', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:15:47Z', 'content': '(MANCHESTER, N.H.) — A woman who was severely burned in a domestic violence attack in Vermont is hoping for a second face transplant after doctors recently discovered tissue damage that likely will lead to the loss of her donor face.\r\nCarmen Blandin Tarleton,… [+2963 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Billypenn.com'}, 'author': 'Layla A. Jones', 'title': "Why 'Unlike Agholor' was trending on Philly Twitter - Billy Penn", 'description': 'Former firefighter Hakim Laws saved some babies and made a whole city laugh.', 'url': 'https://billypenn.com/2019/09/23/why-unlike-agholor-was-trending-on-twitter-all-the-best-comments-about-phillys-new-hero/', 'urlToImage': 'https://billypenn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/unlikeagholor-1200x630.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:15:00Z', 'content': 'On this day in Philadelphia sports history, an Eagles fan became a national hero.\r\nHis name is Hakim Laws, and he’s a former firefighter. But his popularity actually does not derive from his recent valiant efforts in rescuing babies being tossed from a burnin… [+2123 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Gizmodo.com'}, 'author': 'Ed Cara', 'title': 'A Brain-Infecting Virus Carried by Mosquitoes Is Spreading Far and Wide This Year - Gizmodo', 'description': 'Over the weekend, health officials in several states reported more cases and deaths linked to the Eastern Equine Encephalitis (EEE) virus. The number of cases, while still small, is set to make 2019 the worst recorded year for EEE in recent history—and it may…', 'url': 'https://gizmodo.com/a-brain-infecting-virus-carried-by-mosquitoes-is-spread-1838370317', 'urlToImage': 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--9iNIZGMR--/c_fill,fl_progressive,g_center,h_900,q_80,w_1600/cydaw04kddkqrfby6swu.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:10:00Z', 'content': 'Over the weekend, health officials in several states reported more cases and deaths linked to the Eastern Equine Encephalitis (EEE) virus. The number of cases, while still small, is set to make 2019 the worst recorded year for EEE in recent historyand it may … [+5280 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Staradvertiser.com'}, 'author': 'Associated Press', 'title': 'Hundreds of thousands stranded as 178-year-old travel agency collapses - Honolulu Star-Advertiser', 'description': 'LONDON >> Families stranded, honeymoons and vacations canceled, thousands of workers laid off: The sudden collapse of British tour company Thomas Cook and its network of airlines and hotels sowed chaos for hundreds of thousands of travelers and businesses aro…', 'url': 'https://www.staradvertiser.com/2019/09/23/breaking-news/hundreds-of-thousands-stranded-as-178-year-old-travel-agency-collapses/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.staradvertiser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/web1_9073405-52c8be0cfb994c5a94e047711293cb19.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:08:12Z', 'content': 'LONDON &gt;&gt; Families stranded, honeymoons and vacations canceled, thousands of workers laid off: The sudden collapse of British tour company Thomas Cook and its network of airlines and hotels sowed chaos for hundreds of thousands of travelers and business… [+5429 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'nbc-news', 'name': 'NBC News'}, 'author': 'Sara G. Miller', 'title': 'FDA expands blood pressure drug recall, again - NBC News', 'description': 'The Food and Drug Administration is again expanding its recall of blood pressure drugs due to contamination with a cancer-linked chemical.', 'url': 'https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/fda-expands-blood-pressure-drug-recall-again-n1057801', 'urlToImage': 'https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_39/3022271/190923-losartan-comp-ew-341p_576b22fc6a7cc9dc239779cc33028ac0.nbcnews-fp-1200-630.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:54:00Z', 'content': "The Food and Drug Administration is again expanding its recall of widely prescribed blood pressure drugs due to contamination with a cancer-linked chemical.\r\nMonday's announcement targets an additional five lots of the generic drug losartan made by Torrent Ph… [+789 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Gamespot.com'}, 'author': 'Steve Watts', 'title': 'Watch Last Of Us 2 State Of Play: Start Time, What To Expect, And More - GameSpot', 'description': 'Sony is preparing to detail its upcoming PS4 game plans with a new State of Play presentation, and you can watch it all go down right here.', 'url': 'https://www.gamespot.com/articles/watch-last-of-us-2-state-of-play-start-time-what-t/1100-6470025/', 'urlToImage': 'https://gamespot1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/screen_kubrick/1585/15855271/3583637-3165123-screen_tlou2_teaser_05.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:47:00Z', 'content': "GameSpot may get a commission from retail offers.Sony is preparing another of its State of Play presentations, promising big PS4 news on the horizon. Whereas Microsoft's Inside Xbox streams come semi-regularly and Nintendo Directs are often themed around big … [+1732 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'fox-news', 'name': 'Fox News'}, 'author': 'Christopher Carbone', 'title': 'Indonesia fires turn sky an eerie blood red - Fox News', 'description': "Skies over one province in Indonesia turned blood red over the weekend as a result of the country's widespread wildfires.", 'url': 'https://www.foxnews.com/science/indonesia-fires-sky-blood-red', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2019/09/indonesia-fire-getty-images.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:44:28Z', 'content': "Skies over one province in Indonesia turned blood red over the weekend as a result of the country's widespread wildfires.\r\nThe annual fires in Indonesia are known to create a haze that blankets the entire region.\r\nOne resident in Jambi province, who captured … [+2141 chars]"}]}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I wonder if there is a script to separate all of this into a readable file

Comment: Please share the full output, as that is incomplete together with an expected out so we can have something to work with. At first it seems like a dictionary with lists and dictionaries in it.

Comment: @CeliusStingher just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_data= {'status': 'ok', 'totalResults': 38, 'articles': [{'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': 'Boeing to pay bereaved 737 families $144500 each - BBC News', 'description': 'The financial assistance fund Boeing set up after the crashes has started accepting claims.', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/business-49803068', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/104F2/production/_108920866_gettyimages-1167365351.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T22:38:36Z', 'content': 'Image copyrightGetty ImagesImage caption\r\n Families are to receive about $144,500 each\r\nFamilies who lost relatives in fatal Boeing 737 Max air crashes are set to receive about $144,500 (£116,200) each from the company.\r\nThe money comes from a $50m financial … [+2097 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Deadline.com'}, 'author': "Amanda N'Duka,Anthony D'Alessandro, Amanda N'Duka, Anthony D'Alessandro", 'title': 'Jonah Hill In Talks For Matt Reeves’ ‘The Batman’ At Warner Bros - Deadline', 'description': 'EXCLUSIVE:\xa0We are hearing that two-time Oscar nominee Jonah Hill is in talks to play a villain in the upcoming Warner Bros reboot The Batman, which stars Robert Pattinson as the Caped Crusader. Dea…', 'url': 'https://deadline.com/2019/09/jonah-hill-in-talks-for-matt-reeves-the-batman-at-warner-bros-1202742916/', 'urlToImage': 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/jonah-hill-e1569279089585.jpg?w=1024', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T22:08:00Z', 'content': 'EXCLUSIVE:\xa0We are hearing that two-time Oscar nominee Jonah Hill is in talks to play a villain in the upcoming Warner Bros reboot The Batman, which stars Robert Pattinson as the Caped Crusader. Deals aren’t signed yet, but that’s what we are hearing at this m… [+931 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'politico', 'name': 'Politico'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/daniellippman', 'title': 'The intelligence watchdog at the center of Ukraine firestorm - POLITICO', 'description': 'President Trump appointed Michael Atkinson, a widely respected career DOJ official, to keep the intelligence community accountable. Now, he’s unexpectedly in the middle of a presidential scandal.', 'url': 'https://www.politico.com/story/2019/09/23/atkinson-trump-ukraine-whistleblower-scandal-1508594', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.politico.com/ef/de/f06302cf41f1adb23c46ec335fd7/20190923-donald-trump-gty-773.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:47:00Z', 'content': 'President Donald Trump. | Spencer Platt/Getty Images\r\nThe intelligence communitys chief watchdog, Michael Atkinson, is known to his peers and colleagues as a highly cautious straight shooter who tends to keep his head down. \r\nSo when he sounded the alarm to C… [+1646 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Vox.com'}, 'author': 'Alex Ward', 'title': 'France, Germany, UK say Iran is responsible for Saudi Arabia attacks - Vox.com', 'description': '“It is clear for us that Iran bears responsibility for this attack,” the leaders of the three European powers said. “There is no other explanation.”', 'url': 'https://www.vox.com/world/2019/9/23/20880639/france-germany-uk-iran-saudi-statement', 'urlToImage': 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/15u8motId_osZOIlMdIE82FpJ20=/0x74:4584x2474/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19226096/1164153206.jpg.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:36:00Z', 'content': 'The Trump administration has blamed Iran for the attacks on two vital oil facilities belonging to Saudi Arabias state-run oil company Aramco nine days ago. That assertion was met with deep skepticism by politicians, experts, and even some US allies, mostly be… [+2588 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'cnbc', 'name': 'CNBC'}, 'author': 'Berkeley Lovelace Jr.', 'title': 'Federal prosecutors in California reportedly open criminal probe of vaping company Juul - msnNOW', 'description': "The probe by the U.S. attorney's office of the Northern District of California is in its early stages, the Journal reported, citing people familiar with the matter.", 'url': 'https://www.cnbc.com/2019/09/23/federal-prosecutors-conducting-criminal-probe-into-juul-wsj.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106040688-15640809580022019-02-06t180654z_1746289374_rc1220cf81f0_rtrmadp_3_global-vaping.jpg?v=1566493861', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:30:00Z', 'content': "Federal prosecutors in California are conducting a criminal probe into e-cigarette maker Juul, the Wall Street Journal reported Monday.\r\nThe probe, by the U.S. attorney's office of the Northern District of California, is in the early stages, the Journal repor… [+1291 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Cheatsheet.com'}, 'author': 'Julia Mullaney', 'title': "Here's Why You Won't See Prince Harry and Meghan Markle When They Fly Commercial -- Even If You're on Their Flight - Showbiz Cheat Sheet", 'description': "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle might be flying commercial, but you probably won't even notice.", 'url': 'https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/you-wont-see-prince-harry-meghan-markle-when-they-fly-commercial.html/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.cheatsheet.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Prince-Harry-Meghan-Markle-5.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:28:06Z', 'content': 'Prince Harry and Meghan Markle recently flew to South Africa — and they didnt take a private jet. After receiving backlash, the royal couple decided to fly commercial during their South Africa tour and will likely do so from now on (unless they choose to fly … [+4405 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Cnet.com'}, 'author': 'Richard Nieva', 'title': 'Google Play Pass launches subscription service with 350 games and apps for Android - CNET', 'description': 'The service includes games and other types of apps.', 'url': 'https://www.cnet.com/news/google-play-pass-launches-subscription-service-with-350-games-and-apps-for-android/', 'urlToImage': 'https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/lqMwloR5D-TSYlelhCE_ni0H6k0=/756x567/2019/09/23/a10682f1-d50d-4a55-82bc-c127f5da2c0f/play-pass-titles.png', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:20:00Z', 'content': 'Google to Apple: "Game on!"\r\nGetty Images\r\nGoogle on Monday launched Play Pass, a monthly subscription service that gives people access to a library of games and other apps on Google\'s Play Store, as the search giant experiments with new pricing models for it… [+2451 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': "'Toilet trouble' for Narendra Modi and Bill Gates - BBC News", 'description': "Why has an award honouring India's PM for building toilets for the poor become controversial?", 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-49738605', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/AB2D/production/_108912834_gettyimages-1170210337.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:19:13Z', 'content': "Image copyrightGetty Images\r\nIndian Prime Minster Narendra Modi's high-profile visit to the US includes an evening in New York, where he will be honoured for a flagship government scheme. But the celebrity event has turned controversial. \r\nIt all began with a… [+7088 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Bbc.com'}, 'author': 'https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews', 'title': 'US policeman suspended for arresting two six-year-olds - BBC News', 'description': 'A six-year-old girl was handcuffed and charged with battery, her grandmother told US media.', 'url': 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-49803733', 'urlToImage': 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/3DAF/production/_108919751_gettyimages-914038200.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:16:11Z', 'content': 'Image copyrightGetty ImagesImage caption\r\n At least one child was handcuffed (file photo)\r\nA US police officer has been suspended after arresting two six-year-olds at a school in Orlando, Florida. \r\nOne of the two was handcuffed after throwing a tantrum and k… [+1921 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'engadget', 'name': 'Engadget'}, 'author': 'Amrita Khalid', 'title': "Amazon's version of AirPods will reportedly offer fitness tracking - Engadget", 'description': "We still know very little about Amazon's AirPods competitor.", 'url': 'https://www.engadget.com/2019/09/23/amazon-version-of-airpods-will-reportedly-offer-fitness-tracking/', 'urlToImage': 'https://o.aolcdn.com/images/dims?thumbnail=1200%2C630&quality=80&image_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fo.aolcdn.com%2Fimages%2Fdims%3Fresize%3D2000%252C2000%252Cshrink%26image_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fs.yimg.com%252Fos%252Fcreatr-images%252F2019-09%252F5c09c1c0-de3f-11e9-bdfe-950638385d12%26client%3Da1acac3e1b3290917d92%26signature%3D523d1e94bea45e69a4c8d8d0236e9cf292f6db5e&client=amp-blogside-v2&signature=a67c5ed6bc83cff482093753cb6296b2e24b6688', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:11:27Z', 'content': "It's unknown when exactly we'll catch a glimpse of these earbuds. Amazon is expected to unveil a host of new devices at its big hardware event on September 25th. As is typical, the company has remained silent on what exactly we can expect from the event. If l… [+621 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Yahoo.com'}, 'author': None, 'title': 'Kourtney Kardashian & Scott Disick Are Still Managing to Co-Parent Through Nanny Disaster - Yahoo Lifestyle', 'description': "It all began with a nanny and a scratch. The nanny quit, but the story just won't: Kourtney Kardashian and co-parent Scott Disick are still fielding comments, questions and downright judgment from all sides regarding their daughter Penelope, 7, who allegedly …", 'url': 'https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/kourtney-kardashian-scott-disick-still-210906682.html', 'urlToImage': 'https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/3iaYPDZKhx7B6hPQNcT9GA--~B/dz0wO3NtPTE7YXBwaWQ9eXRhY2h5b24-/https://media.zenfs.com/en-US/sheknows_79/aee9db9ca589dd39edc80b04f0c273e3', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T21:09:00Z', 'content': 'Click here to read the full article.\r\nIt all began with a nanny and a scratch.\xa0The nanny quit, but the story just wont:\xa0Kourtney Kardashian\xa0and co-parent\xa0Scott Disick\xa0are still fielding comments, questions and downright judgment from all sides regarding their… [+3403 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Statnews.com'}, 'author': 'Helen Branswell', 'title': 'Vaccination strategy in long-running Ebola outbreak comes under fire - STAT', 'description': 'The World Health Organization’s vaccination strategy in the long-running Ebola outbreak in the Democratic Republic of the Congo is coming under fire.', 'url': 'https://www.statnews.com/2019/09/23/vaccination-strategy-in-long-running-ebola-outbreak-comes-under-fire/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/GettyImages-1160258652-1024x576.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:57:39Z', 'content': 'The World Health Organizations vaccination strategy in the long-running Ebola outbreak in the Democratic Republic of the Congo is coming under fire, with Doctors Without Borders accusing the agency of rationing vaccines and calling for an independent committe… [+8661 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Giants.com'}, 'author': 'John Schmeelk, Dan Salomone, Lance Medow', 'title': 'Cover 3: Takeaways from Giants vs. Buccaneers - Giants.com', 'description': "The Giants.com staffers give their reactions to Sunday's win in Tampa Bay.", 'url': 'https://www.giants.com/news/cover-3-takeaways-from-giants-vs-buccaneers', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.clubs.nfl.com/image/private/t_editorial_landscape_12_desktop/giants/axk3hdqjrvhv41ehktww', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:56:01Z', 'content': 'As Pat Shurmur pointed out in his postgame press conference, there are things a quarterback can be trained to improve upon. A quarterback can be trained to protect the football when he is in the pocket. A quarterback can be trained to get the ball out quicker… [+1987 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'time', 'name': 'Time'}, 'author': 'Associated Press', 'title': 'Face Transplant Recipient May Need a New Donor After Doctors Discover Tissue Damage - TIME', 'description': 'A woman who was severely burned in a domestic violence attack may have a second face transplant after doctors discovered tissue damage.', 'url': 'https://time.com/5684395/face-transplant-vermont-woman/', 'urlToImage': 'https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/face-transplant-recipient-tissue.jpg?quality=85&w=1024&h=628&crop=1', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:15:47Z', 'content': '(MANCHESTER, N.H.) — A woman who was severely burned in a domestic violence attack in Vermont is hoping for a second face transplant after doctors recently discovered tissue damage that likely will lead to the loss of her donor face.\r\nCarmen Blandin Tarleton,… [+2963 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Billypenn.com'}, 'author': 'Layla A. Jones', 'title': "Why 'Unlike Agholor' was trending on Philly Twitter - Billy Penn", 'description': 'Former firefighter Hakim Laws saved some babies and made a whole city laugh.', 'url': 'https://billypenn.com/2019/09/23/why-unlike-agholor-was-trending-on-twitter-all-the-best-comments-about-phillys-new-hero/', 'urlToImage': 'https://billypenn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/unlikeagholor-1200x630.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:15:00Z', 'content': 'On this day in Philadelphia sports history, an Eagles fan became a national hero.\r\nHis name is Hakim Laws, and he’s a former firefighter. But his popularity actually does not derive from his recent valiant efforts in rescuing babies being tossed from a burnin… [+2123 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Gizmodo.com'}, 'author': 'Ed Cara', 'title': 'A Brain-Infecting Virus Carried by Mosquitoes Is Spreading Far and Wide This Year - Gizmodo', 'description': 'Over the weekend, health officials in several states reported more cases and deaths linked to the Eastern Equine Encephalitis (EEE) virus. The number of cases, while still small, is set to make 2019 the worst recorded year for EEE in recent history—and it may…', 'url': 'https://gizmodo.com/a-brain-infecting-virus-carried-by-mosquitoes-is-spread-1838370317', 'urlToImage': 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--9iNIZGMR--/c_fill,fl_progressive,g_center,h_900,q_80,w_1600/cydaw04kddkqrfby6swu.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:10:00Z', 'content': 'Over the weekend, health officials in several states reported more cases and deaths linked to the Eastern Equine Encephalitis (EEE) virus. The number of cases, while still small, is set to make 2019 the worst recorded year for EEE in recent historyand it may … [+5280 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Staradvertiser.com'}, 'author': 'Associated Press', 'title': 'Hundreds of thousands stranded as 178-year-old travel agency collapses - Honolulu Star-Advertiser', 'description': 'LONDON >> Families stranded, honeymoons and vacations canceled, thousands of workers laid off: The sudden collapse of British tour company Thomas Cook and its network of airlines and hotels sowed chaos for hundreds of thousands of travelers and businesses aro…', 'url': 'https://www.staradvertiser.com/2019/09/23/breaking-news/hundreds-of-thousands-stranded-as-178-year-old-travel-agency-collapses/', 'urlToImage': 'https://www.staradvertiser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/web1_9073405-52c8be0cfb994c5a94e047711293cb19.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T20:08:12Z', 'content': 'LONDON &gt;&gt; Families stranded, honeymoons and vacations canceled, thousands of workers laid off: The sudden collapse of British tour company Thomas Cook and its network of airlines and hotels sowed chaos for hundreds of thousands of travelers and business… [+5429 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'nbc-news', 'name': 'NBC News'}, 'author': 'Sara G. Miller', 'title': 'FDA expands blood pressure drug recall, again - NBC News', 'description': 'The Food and Drug Administration is again expanding its recall of blood pressure drugs due to contamination with a cancer-linked chemical.', 'url': 'https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/fda-expands-blood-pressure-drug-recall-again-n1057801', 'urlToImage': 'https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_39/3022271/190923-losartan-comp-ew-341p_576b22fc6a7cc9dc239779cc33028ac0.nbcnews-fp-1200-630.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:54:00Z', 'content': "The Food and Drug Administration is again expanding its recall of widely prescribed blood pressure drugs due to contamination with a cancer-linked chemical.\r\nMonday's announcement targets an additional five lots of the generic drug losartan made by Torrent Ph… [+789 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': None, 'name': 'Gamespot.com'}, 'author': 'Steve Watts', 'title': 'Watch Last Of Us 2 State Of Play: Start Time, What To Expect, And More - GameSpot', 'description': 'Sony is preparing to detail its upcoming PS4 game plans with a new State of Play presentation, and you can watch it all go down right here.', 'url': 'https://www.gamespot.com/articles/watch-last-of-us-2-state-of-play-start-time-what-t/1100-6470025/', 'urlToImage': 'https://gamespot1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/screen_kubrick/1585/15855271/3583637-3165123-screen_tlou2_teaser_05.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:47:00Z', 'content': "GameSpot may get a commission from retail offers.Sony is preparing another of its State of Play presentations, promising big PS4 news on the horizon. Whereas Microsoft's Inside Xbox streams come semi-regularly and Nintendo Directs are often themed around big … [+1732 chars]"}, {'source': {'id': 'fox-news', 'name': 'Fox News'}, 'author': 'Christopher Carbone', 'title': 'Indonesia fires turn sky an eerie blood red - Fox News', 'description': "Skies over one province in Indonesia turned blood red over the weekend as a result of the country's widespread wildfires.", 'url': 'https://www.foxnews.com/science/indonesia-fires-sky-blood-red', 'urlToImage': 'https://static.foxnews.com/foxnews.com/content/uploads/2019/09/indonesia-fire-getty-images.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2019-09-23T19:44:28Z', 'content': "Skies over one province in Indonesia turned blood red over the weekend as a result of the country's widespread wildfires.\r\nThe annual fires in Indonesia are known to create a haze that blankets the entire region.\r\nOne resident in Jambi province, who captured … [+2141 chars]"}]}

# Create pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data['articles'])

# Store your data to csv file
df.to_csv('articles.csv', sep=";")
```

If you use `pandas` this will be the format of your dataframe. 
[image]

If you are not an expert in programming you can open the csv file you just created with `Excel` and work on that.